# use firefox console in userscript

Tags: javascript, firefox, command-line, greasemonkey, userscripts

How can one use the firefox console from within a userscript?

I'd like to write a userscript to take a screenshot via

`screenshot --fullpage`

and save it to disk.

edit:
[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) doesn't work for me.

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: Is this intendet by the developers or just not possible for some reasons?